# Selecting Thousands of Paths

Tags: eps

I’m brand new to Gravit. I purchased an EPS file from Etsy with a bunch of illustrated clip art. I need to select one of the illustrations so that I can use it in a design. When I use the selection tool, it just selects one tiny path of the illustration. How can I select the whole illustration (but not every illustration in the file)?

Comment: I don't know Gravit, but isn't there some kind of selection tool with which you can drag a rectangle around the illustration you want to select?

Comment: I'd wager few designers have experience with a gravity simulator app.

Comment: .. and you can click drag with the Direct Selection tool or Magic Lasso tool.